# How to release unused textLabels of UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image: I've detected that the textLabels of UITableViewCell are using too much memory. How can I release them?]

I've detected that the textLabels of UITableViewCell are using too much memory. How can I release them?

Using weak reference for the string it display and autorelease pool doesn't help, here is my source code of cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }

    @autoreleasepool
    {
        //text
        __weak NSString *text = @"Home";
        cell.textLabel.text = text;

        //image
        cell.imageView.image = nil;

        //load image asynchronous
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^(void)
                       {

                           NSString *urlStr = @"http://st.vitalk.vn/img/2015/4_13/tulinh_2kjp5i61imfp7_vitalk_9927e8_0x122_max.jpg";
                           NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
                           NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

                           [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                                              queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                                  completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
                            {
                                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                                if (image)
                                {

                                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                                        cell.imageView.image = image;
                                        [cell setNeedsLayout];
                                    });
                                }

                            }];
                       });
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: what the f are you trying to do? :D your code is exactly the same as just ignoring the autoreleasepool and the weak - do you know what each of these is supposed to do?

Comment: Text labels should not be using too much memory. If they are, then you're doing something incorrectly. You need to post your code for cellForRowAtIndexPath, and your cell code if you have a custom cell class.

Comment: How I can release the memory?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. You shouldn't need to release the memory; you need to fix the problem, not the symptoms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing in that instruments profile that strikes me as a memory issue. There's a lot of allocations, but only 4.6mb of actual memory used by the labels. UITableView does a lot of stuff behind the scenes to keep memory usage down, so unless you're keeping explicit references to cells or their subviews, I'd put the number of allocations down to UITableView housekeeping.

I'd definitely remove all of the code around autoreleasepools, weak references and GCD as it's unnecessary, and then only look at memory usage if you start to notice issues such as the memory usage of your app consistently climbing as you navigate around the app, or the app starts being killed by the OS because of its memory usage.